# Using Tor in Iran for the first time. User Guide.

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship

I am about to go to Iran next week. I've got Tor's Browser Bundle installed, but will I need anything else configured to ensure anonymous and uncontrolled browsing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make it harder for people to detect the fact that you using Tor and to make harder to censor you by preventing you from connecting to Tor you may want to use bridges. In the current Tor Browser Bundle you can configure those in the startup wizard or by clicking on network settings.

There are multiple ways of getting to know such bridges:

- Know someone running a bridge and ask them for their data
- Visit: https://bridges.torproject.org/
- Sending a mail to:  bridges@bridges.torproject.org containing `get bridges` in the body

If you need further help it is good to know where to get some. help@rt.torproject.org is the way to go, if you have troubles using other channels.