# tor failed to establish a tor network connection 140:9001

Tags: connection

Tried to connect but failed. What should I do?

Log:

```
12/04/2017 08:46:08 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:46:08 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:46:08 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:46:08 ص.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:46:08 ص.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\AbouHager\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
12/04/2017 08:46:08 ص.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12/04/2017 08:46:09 ص.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12/04/2017 08:47:09 ص.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 49E7AD01BB96F6FE3AB8C3B15BD2470B150354DF at 188.165.194.195:9001) 
12/04/2017 08:47:09 ص.100 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
12/04/2017 08:47:09 ص.100 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12/04/2017 08:47:09 ص.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
12/04/2017 08:47:18 ص.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:47:18 ص.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:18 ص.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:47:18 ص.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
12/04/2017 08:47:19 ص.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:19 ص.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:19 ص.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:19 ص.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:47:35 ص.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at 154.35.175.225:443) 
12/04/2017 08:47:35 ص.300 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
12/04/2017 08:47:35 ص.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12/04/2017 08:47:35 ص.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
12/04/2017 08:47:40 ص.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:47:40 ص.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:40 ص.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:47:40 ص.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
12/04/2017 08:47:48 ص.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:48 ص.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:48 ص.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:47:48 ص.700 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:47:57 ص.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host B1726B94885CE3AC3910CA8B60622B97B98E2529 at 185.66.250.141:9001) 
12/04/2017 08:47:57 ص.100 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
12/04/2017 08:47:57 ص.100 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12/04/2017 08:47:57 ص.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
12/04/2017 08:50:49 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:50:49 ص.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/04/2017 08:50:49 ص.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/04/2017 08:50:49 ص.100 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: It's the same error message, but I think the answer on the other question is incorrect, bad time sync would result in an explicit error message. What they're seeing looks more like censorship of TLS connections. Try pluggable transports (`obfs4`, `meek-amazon`, `meek-azure`, `scramblesuit`, etc) and if the defaults don't work, try fetching fresh bridges, see [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/using-tor-in-iran-for-the-first-time-user-guide/1649#1649) for how to get fresh bridges.